# Inorden route html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tree, preorder

how to make a pre-order traversal of elements in a html  tree with javascript

[image]

Img src = http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ (Great Article) ,assume that boxs are a html element

example:

```
function preorderHtml(element patern)
{
 //preorder tree traversal

}
```

Comment: I try to walk in the html tree in pre-order .

Comment: ......... what? Please provide a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```javascript
function traversePreorder(el, indent) {
  indent = (indent || '')
  console.log(indent + el.nodeName); // Do something with the element here...
  for (var i=0; i<el.children.length; i++) {
    traversePreorder(el.children[i], indent + '  ');
  }
}
traversePreorder(document.body);
```

I would probably introduce a second argument which is a function that gets called at each element so that this method could be reused.

```javascript
function traversePreorder(el, func, indent) {
  indent = (indent || '')
  func(el);
  //...
}
traversePreorder(document.body, function(element) {
  console.log(el.nodeName); // Do something here...
});
```